# List<Block> cannot be resolved

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

it says that 'block' cant be resolved even when i have it imported...i am using Eclipse

```
else if (spawn.distance(loc) > 11){

List<Block> blocks = UHCore.blocksBetweenPoints(player.getLocation().add(2, 2, 2), player.getLocation().subtract(2, 2, 2));
    for (Block block : blocks);
        if (block.getType() != Material.AIR)continue;
            if (block.getLocation().distance(spawn)>15){
                block.getWorld().playEffect(block.getLocation(), Effect.MOBSPAWNER_FLAMES, 2);
              }
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? This is essential in finding out the answer to your question.

Comment: @PhotographyBum im trying to write a plugin but that one error is stopping me...i have the 'import org.bukkit.block.Block;' but it says that 'block cannot be resolved' that potion right fire is basically making a forcefield around the players...so they have limited space to move b4 the game starts

Comment: take out the `;` in `if (block.getType() != Material.AIR)continue` since that might be making the code act funny. Also wrap the next if statement in `{}`

Comment: Have you checked to be sure you've added the external library to the project build path?  Also, your for loop should be enclsed in `{}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing to note is that the compiler complains about the `block` variable, not about the `Block` class.

Due to the `;`, your for loop -
`for (Block block : blocks);` - is a for loop that does nothing

The next lines are outside the for loop, so the variable `block` is no longer defined in their scope.

You should remove the `;`.

In addition, you should wrap the for loop in `{}`, since you have two statements that refer to the `block` variable.

The correct code would be :

```
else if (spawn.distance(loc) > 11) {
    List<Block> blocks = UHCore.blocksBetweenPoints(player.getLocation().add(2, 2, 2),  
                                                    player.getLocation().subtract(2, 2, 2));
    for (Block block : blocks) {
        if (block.getType() != Material.AIR)
            continue;
        if (block.getLocation().distance(spawn)>15) {
            block.getWorld().playEffect(block.getLocation(), Effect.MOBSPAWNER_FLAMES, 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i put the for loop in the {} and everything is back to normal..i feel like a nub considering i write all of this and yet i get the simple errors i cant figure out

Comment: @user3904781 Glad I could help. Don't worry about it. It wasn't too easy to spot, or you would've gotten an answer here within a minute or two :)

Comment: @user3904781 If this answer solves your problem, you should click the check mark to mark the question as resolved.